# Streethawk Android Titanium Module

Tags: javascript, android, module, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

- I am using Appcelerator Titanium App. I am trying to Add Streethawk Modules for it.
- iOS works fine providing the "require" module and adding the appkey and init commands in alloy.js
- However, I cannot get the Android Module to register.
- Streethawk documentation has nothing mentioned about Android additions to alloy.js or app.js, nor does the sample app.js for that matter.
- Has anyone been able to get Streethawak Android Titanium module to work and is their a missing documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
var shAnalytics = require('com.streethawk.shanalytics');
shAnalytics.appKey = "APP_KEY";
shAnalytics.setAppKey("APP_KEY");
//Optional, set console debug mode.
shAnalytics.enableLogs(true);
//Mandatory, initialize streethawk SDK.
shAnalytics.streethawkinit();
```